# Why is Windows 10 auto-arranging my icons so often?

Tags: windows-10, icons, desktop

I been having an issue on one of my PC's where the desktop icons will auto-arrange themselves and I am not sure why this is happening. At first it was only happening periodically maybe once every couple months, but now it is happening more often within a week or two. It is kind of frustrating because I like to manually arrange my icons a certain way that I am used to, but they keep moving to an auto-arranged format. Before anyone asks, yes auto arrange icons is turned off.  I know sometimes icons will auto-arrange when you remote into a PC, but I have not been remoting into this PC at all. Makes me wonder if my PC has been compromised and if someone else is remoting into my PC without my knowledge.   I thought about using something like [DesktopOK](http://www.softwareok.com/?Freeware/DesktopOK) and using a script to save the position of my icons daily and just restore them when I notice they moved, but this does not fix the problem of why they are moving in the first place.  I have also considered something like [Rainmeter](https://www.rainmeter.net/) or even a complete reformat to start over.

It would really be nice to find out what is causing this or find out if I should be concerned that my system is compromised and in need of a refresh.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you play any games that run at a different screen resolution?

Comment: Does it happen after a reboot or during use?

Comment: I have not been playing any games and I only notice it when I turn on my PC in the morning.  I leave my PC on most of the day, but shut down at night before bed. I do not notice them move during use.

Comment: It could be that my PC's is just old. I am using an 8 year old motherboard with the fastest CPU it supports and maxed out RAM.

Comment: On some machines I find Explorer crashes from time to time. It restarts automatically, but the desktop and system tray are messed up. I have given up trying to arrange the icons manually. My only suggestion is to rename the icons with a prefix which will auto-arrange them in the order you want them, eg `01 Chrome`, `02 Firefox`, etc, but note that this means that reinstallations and some updates will not remove the old icons and create new icons without the prefix. Not very satisfactory, I know, and I have learned to live with auto-arrange.

Comment: Hmmm...I do get an explorer error when I shutdown at night quit often and I do remember this happening recently. I never put two and two together that this might be the time my icons are auto-arranging. This might be exactly why this is happening. Thanks!

Comment: @AFH It is clear to me now that explorer.exe is crashing time to time when I shutdown my computer and this is what is causing my icons to auto-arrange.   Your answer help resolve my concerns. If you move your comment down to an answer, I can accept as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On some machines I find Explorer crashes from time to time. It restarts automatically, but the desktop, taskbar and system tray are messed up.

I have given up trying to arrange the icons manually. I found a desktop icon layout save/restore, but this was only partially successful and I have given up on using it.

However, I have just tried [DektopOK](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/desktopok-save-restore-icon-positions) and initial tests seem better, though I haven't yet used it enough to recommend it. I haven't found a solution for the taskbar and system tray.

My only other suggestion is to rename the icons with a prefix which will auto-arrange them in the order you want them, eg `01 Chrome`, `02 Firefox`, etc, but note that this means that reinstallations and some updates will not remove the old icons and create new icons without the prefix.

I know that this is unsatisfactory, especially with 66 icons on my desktop, and so far I have just learned to live with finding my short-cuts when auto-arranged, not helped by the fact that the `All Users` desktop and my own are ordered alphabetically in separate, but abutted groups.

Comment: I have experience using DesktopOK, it does as advertised but if screen layout or resolution is different from the saved configuration it doesn't really know what to do; although it doesn't claim to either.  That means making it work is up to the user.

Comment: @Damon - Thanks for the observation: I have most often needed to restore the icon layout on restoring the original resolution after a change (eg after going into safe mode), so it should be ideal for that.